# Read InsertCommand before it gets sent to SQL

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

Good morning,

I have an ASPX page with an UpdatePanel containing a Gridview and SqlDataSource control. In the SqlDataSource control I specify an InsertCommand. I would like to be able to read the InsertCommand that my page will send to the SQL database. Reading the following

```
mySqlDataSource.InsertCommand
```

in code-behind gives me the InsertCommand with @parameters rather than the actual value for each parameter that will be sent to SQL.

Is there a way to read the final InsertCommand that will actually be sent to the database for execution?

EDIT: Please note, my question could apply to Select, Update, Insert or any command that is sent from my ASPX page to SQL. The command must be converted to a language that SQL can interpret and execute and that is the very version of the command that I am trying to read.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should subscribe to the Inserting event of your DataSource.

Then, in your Inserting_Handler, you may browse the your DataSource.InsertParameters Collection

```
private void On_Inserting(Object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{

    var txt = e.Command.CommandText;
    //the parameters names and values are in e.Command.Parameters
}
```

Hope this will help

Comment: @leoinlios edited my answer . The query is a prepared statememnt you must loop ththrough the parameters to get their value.

Comment: Thanks jbl, this worked. Reading CommandText is (nearly) the same as reading InsertCommand in the aspx, so not much point, but as you said, accessing e.Command.Parameters[0].Value gives me the value of the first parameter. I am really surprised that there is no simple way to read the final and fully rendered Insert command in one go. Surely, the entire statement must be converted to SQL language at some stage! Thanks again for your help.